# Is there any way I can mock a Claims Principal in my ASP.NET MVC web application?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity, claims

I've got some `ASP.NET MVC` controller code that checks if a user is authenticated and if so, it checks to see if it has a specific claim. Works fine.

I've got some unit tests and I need to mock out an `IPrincipal` (which is easy to do) ... but I'm not sure how to check for the claims! I usually do something like

```
public static ClaimsPrincipal ClaimsPrincipal(this Controller controller)
{
    return controller.User as ClaimsPrincipal;
}
```

and some controller code ...

```
this.ClaimsPrincipal().HasClaim(x => x.......);
```

but this all fails when I test this in my Unit Test .. because I'm not sure how I can `mock` the `ClaimsPrincipal`

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Also most of the methods are virtual so those are mock-able.

Answer (score 13):

Mocking the ClaimsPrincipal isnt too difficult

```
var cp = new Mock<ClaimsPrincipal>();
cp.Setup(m => m.HasClaim(It.IsAny<string>(),It.IsAny<string>()))
  .Returns(true);
```

However depending on how your controller gains access to it will. Have a look at this Question [How to mock Controller.User using moq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758066/how-to-mock-controller-user-using-moq)

which would give you something like this:

```
var cp = new Mock<ClaimsPrincipal>();
cp.Setup(m => m.HasClaim(It.IsAny<string>(), It.IsAny<string>())).Returns(true);

var sut = new UtilityController();

var contextMock = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
contextMock.Setup(ctx => ctx.User).Returns(cp.Object);

var controllerContextMock = new Mock<ControllerContext>();
controllerContextMock.Setup(con => con.HttpContext).Returns(contextMock.Object);

sut.ControllerContext = controllerContextMock.Object;

var viewresult = sut.Index();
```

Answer (score 7):

I am not sure what you mean with "mock". But you can simply create a ClaimsPrincipal from scratch. First create a ClaimsIdentity - add the claims and authentication method you need. Then wrap it with a ClaimsPrincipal.

Answer (score 0):

you can declare and pass a real object as the follow example:

```
var controller = new ExampleController();
var user = new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(new Claim[] {
                                        new Claim(JwtClaimIdentifiers.Rol, "viewer"),
                                   }, "Test"));
            controller.ControllerContext = new ControllerContext();
            controller.ControllerContext.HttpContext = new DefaultHttpContext { User = user };
```