# Mocking user in a controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mocking, moq

I'm tyring to use Moq to determine if a user has a certain role.  I tried the following example in the default MVC project ([How to mock Controller.User using moq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758066/how-to-mock-controller-user-using-moq)), however I'm getting the following error when running the test.

> Expected invocation on the mock at least once, but was never
>   performed: p => p.IsInRole("admin")

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void HomeControllerReturnsIndexViewWhenUserIsAdmin()
    {
        var homeController = new HomeController();

        var userMock = new Mock<IPrincipal>();
        userMock.Setup(p => p.IsInRole("admin")).Returns(true);

        var contextMock = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
        contextMock.SetupGet(ctx => ctx.User)
                   .Returns(userMock.Object);

        var controllerContextMock = new Mock<ControllerContext>();
        controllerContextMock.SetupGet(con => con.HttpContext)
                             .Returns(contextMock.Object);

        homeController.ControllerContext = controllerContextMock.Object;
        var result = homeController.Index();
        userMock.Verify(p => p.IsInRole("admin"));
        Assert.AreEqual(((ViewResult)result).ViewName, "Index");
    }
```

It sure looks like IsInRole("admin") is being called, so I'm not sure why I'm getting this error.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Moq's internals, but how Moq determines [String equality](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus) may be an issue.  Try declaring `final String ADMIN = "admin";` and then use `p.IsInRole(ADMIN)` to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: Does the controller code explicitly calls `IsInRole("admin")` or is it just a filter attribute? (If it is the later then you may just want to check that the [attribute exists](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/669175/unit-testing-asp-net-mvc-authorize-attribute-to-verify-redirect-to-login-page))

Comment: Are you able to update your question with the method under test ? Usually you get this error when the method has not been called correctly or the setup is not configured correctly.

Comment: @WhiskerBiscuit Do you still have the same issue?

Comment: @Daniel J.G. is right. It is possible to mock `homeController.ControllerContext.User.IsInRole("admin")` if it is called within the `Index()` method.

Answer (score 1):

You're never calling

```
userMock.Object.IsInRole("admin")
```

You are setting it up such that

```
userMock.Object.IsInRole("admin") == true
```

and you are trying to verify that it was called in such a way, but the call to `Verify` fails as you never called `IsInRole("admin")` manually and neither did the `Index` method of the `HomeController`.