# Test an Asp.Net Controller action method which uses User.Identity.Name?

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing, mstest

I have the following test method for an Asp.Net controller action method.

```
[TestMethod]
public void Get()
{
    var controller = new MyController();
    var result = controller.GetAListOfRecords();
    Assert.IsNotNull(result);
    Assert.IsTrue(result.Count() > 0);
}
```

And the action is

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Users")]
public IQueryable<MyModel> GetAListOfRecords()
{
    var user = User.Identity.Name; // null when called from the test method
    var q = from t in ........
            select t;
    return return string.IsNullOrEmpty(user) ? Enumerable.Empty<MyModel>().AsQueryable() : q;
}
```

However, the `var user = User.Identity.Name` will not get current user name in the test class (it will actually be assigned an empty string). Is it possible to set `user` in the test method?

**Update:**
I tried the following in the test class but `.....Identity.Name` is read-only.

```
controller.RequestContext.Principal.Identity.Name = @"mdynycmas\wangyi";
```

Comment: I believe it is. However, I'm not sure. Have you tried configure the authentication on the test project? You may sign the user inside the constructor of the `TestClass`.

Comment: Can you give some details on how to sign in in the test class? It seems need to add all the dependent asp.net dlls too?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you're using the User property on your Controller object. This property is using the underlying HttpContext.Current. You need to mock the HttpContextBase and return a test user, see for instance [How to mock Controller.User using moq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/758066/how-to-mock-controller-user-using-moq).

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement some mocks in your unit tests. Also I suggest you to remove your direct dependency of HttpContext, and better create a wrapper object instead, so you can mock it easily. [See more information in this link](http://volaresystems.com/blog/post/2010/08/19/Dont-mock-HttpContext) about this approach.

Hope it helps!